# I tried installing react-elastic-carousel

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-elastic-carousel

> PS S:\mindriser\ooty-app> npm install --save react-elastic-carousel

> > > npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: ooty-app@0.1.0 npm

> ERR! Found: react@18.2.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!
> react@"^18.2.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not
> resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"15 - 17" from
> react-elastic-carousel@0.11.5 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react-elastic-carousel npm ERR!
> react-elastic-carousel@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix

> the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See

> C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full
> report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-24T15_16_34_714Z-debug-0.log
>
> I tried installing react-elastic-carousel and I expected the package
> to get installed without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you most likely want to downgrade you npm version to 15 - 17

or you can try:

```
npm install --save react-elastic-carousel --force
```

this forces the install but it can give you a broken package

Comment: Yeah it installed the package but still many errors are there. How can we fix solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the package with:

```
npm install @itseasy21/react-elastic-carousel
```

Then import carousel with:

```
import Carousal from "@itseasy21/react-elastic-carousel";
```

This worked for me, it should solve your issue.